How to set up a Bayesian model properly - an example with a smartphone dataset
I'm starting with Bayesian modeling. In the book Learning Bayesian Models with R by M. Kodulevy there's an exercise based on a UCI dataset (chapter 3, ex. 2). The exercise goes like this: there are two variables x and y which are signals from an accelerometer of a smartphone. We model acceleration using these two variables. The author writes: "...let's assume that the acceleration follows a normal distribution. Let's also assume a normal prior distribution for the mean values of acceleration with a hyperparameter for a mean that is uniformly distributed in the interval (-0.5, 0.5) and known variance equal to 1." And I don't really know how to set up the model. What I'm not sure about is "normal prior" vs "uniformly distributed". Is the following model correct? What prior should be used for $\sigma$?
$a_i$ ~ $N(a | \mu, \sigma^2)$
$\mu$ ~ $N(\mu_{0}, 1)$
$\mu_{0}$ ~ $Uniform(-0.5, 0.5)$
$\sigma$ ~ ?

Where are x and y in the equations you have so far? $\sigma$ can be modelled with a gamma, half cauchy, exponential or other positive distribution.

Not an answer, but perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

@DirkN, x and y are somewhat incorporated in $a_i$ terms, however there's no explicit explanation in the exercise. But let's assume we have a formula for it where x and y are used. How do You understand the exercise?

"Known variance equal to 1" is English for $\sigma^2=1.$  But why do you introduce two mean parameters $\mu$ and $\mu_0$?

@whuber, I was considering an alternative model: $a_i$ ~ $N(a | \mu, 1)$, $\mu$ ~ $Uniform(-0.5, 0.5)$. Do you think it's more appropriate?

That's a more accurate representation of what the exercise asks you to do.
